# TypeScript - Property 'length' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript

I am writing a helper function to compare two arrays in TypeScript.

```
function areArraysEqual(arr1: number[], arr2: number[]): boolean {
  if (arr1 || arr2) {
    return false;
  }
  if (arr1 == arr2) {
    return true;
  }
  if (arr1.length != arr2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let i of arr1) {
    if (arr1[i] != arr2) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

What does the error `Property 'length' does not exist on type 'never'.` mean, which I am getting for `arr1.length` and `arr1.length`?

Comment: `if (arr1 || arr2) {` is always going to pass. Therefore, none of the other code would run.

Comment: @aquinq also doesn't make much sense. Arrays are always truthy. Negating them would be always `false`, so `false || false` is `false`. Unless `strictNullChecks` is disabled but if it was, the in the question wouldn't show up, either.

Comment: Oh yes, totally my mistake. But the error message is kind of misleading, I believe. Thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set `strictNullChecks` in your tsconfig to `true` (which seems to be the case), you cannot pass `null` or `undefined` to `areArraysEqual`. There is no need for the **first two conditions** in the function body. You can simplify the function like this:

```
function areArraysEqual(arr1: number[], arr2: number[]): boolean {
  if (arr1.length != arr2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let i of arr1) {
    if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

About the misleading error - this is because the condition `if (arr1 || arr2)` is always `true`, so the rest of the function body don't have any functionality. Therefore typescript will narrow the types of `arr1` and `arr2`. Typescript removes `number[]` from their type sets so they become empty sets, which are `never`. The type `never` has no "length" property.

Also as @Bbrk24 mentioned in the comments, if you think the size of arrays you want to pass, are big, the function can have better performance if you check this condition at the beginning of the function body.

```
if (arr1 == arr2) {
    return true;
}
```

Because when they are the same reference there is no need to go through a large `for` loop.

Comment: The `arr1 == arr2` check is still helpful -- if they're the same reference, there's no need to iterate over them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I come from Java and I think `unreachable code` would have been a lot more helpful.

Comment: One thing: It does not depend on the size of the arrays, that is not the correct conclusion in my opinion. It's just a check for same reference, it can be size=1 as well.

Comment: @AndreasInfo It does not depend on the size. But if the arrays size are big and the arrays are the same reference, the function performance can be better, cause there is no need to iterate over the big array any more.